# Batch find/replace in text or html files

Tags: batch, script, html, find-and-replace

I have a large collection of html files (thousands), and need to change a single character that wasn't displaying properly on some browsers. Is there a quick and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/). It is shareware, but there is a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Says here that Notepad++ is applicable for search&replace for (in this example) 8342 HTML files http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/
Notepad++ is a free source code editor

Comment: not really an answer to a batch script request, unless you know notepad++ also has a CLI interface capable of doing such a task